# Number of features of the model must match the input

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

For some reason the features of this dataset is being interpreted as rows, "Model n_features is 16 and  input n_features is 18189" Where 18189 is the number of rows and 16 is the correct feature list.

The suspect code is here:

```
for var in cat_cols:
    num = LabelEncoder()
    train[var] = num.fit_transform(train[var].astype('str'))
    train['output'] = num.fit_transform(train['output'].astype('str'))

for var in cat_cols:
    num = LabelEncoder()
    test[var] = num.fit_transform(test[var].astype('str'))
    test['output'] = num.fit_transform(test['output'].astype('str'))


clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10)

xTrain = train[list(features)].values
yTrain = train["output"].values

xTest = test[list(features)].values
xTest = test["output"].values 

clf.fit(xTrain,yTrain)
clfProbs = clf.predict(xTest)#Error happens here.
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Sample training date csv

```
tr4,42,"JobCat4","divorced","tertiary","yes",2,"yes","no","unknown",5,"may",0,1,-1,0,"unknown","TypeA"
```

Sample test data csv

```
tst2,47,"JobCat3","married","unknown","no",1506,"yes","no","unknown",5,"may",0,1,-1,0,"unknown",?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small typo - you created the variable `xTest` and then are immediately overwriting to something incorrect. Change the offending lines to:

```
xTest = test[list(features)].values
yTest = test["output"].values
```