# Python Scikit Learn error: ValueError: 'Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 10]'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run a python program that uses scikit-learn to do a binary classification of a 'win' or 'loss' of a hockey game, based off of 2 arrays: 1 array of statistics (like currentInjuries and Goals Against) for each team playing the hockey game. I am used to java debugging, but in Python the stack trace is a lot longer than what i'm used to.

**Should I look at the entire stack trace, or just the most relevant error and focus on solving that?** Ie) the error at the very bottom, which is:

```
File "C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 10]
```

Here is the entire stack trace:

```
pydev debugger: process 1084 is connecting

C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\lda.py:6: DeprecationWarning: lda.LDA has been moved to discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis in 0.17 and will be removed in 0.19
  "in 0.17 and will be removed in 0.19", DeprecationWarning)
canucks_stats: [3, 11, 2, 2]
opposing_stats: [1, 4, 4, 15]
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/!UFV/CIS480/project/NHL-Predictor.py", line 196, in <module>
    for name, (X, y) in [('moon', toms_make_moons(noise=0.3, random_state=0))#,
  File "C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/!UFV/CIS480/project/NHL-Predictor.py", line 113, in toms_make_moons
    X, y = util_shuffle(X, y, random_state=generator)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 285, in shuffle
    return resample(*arrays, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 204, in resample
    check_consistent_length(*arrays)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 10]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error at the very bottom can show you what the error is.And the entire stack trace helps you to find where the error is.

Answer (score -2):

The error at the very bottom can show what the error is. The entire stack trace helps you find where the error is located.

And when you post your question, please always posts the full stack trace (to know in which line you are getting the error). Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

About the error `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 10]`:

`x` should be a 2-dimensional array of size [number_of_samples, number_of_features].You may check it.

and there are some references:

ref1: [ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples [ 6 1786]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379200/valueerror-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-6-1786?rq=1)

ref2:[Loading jpg of different sizes into numpy.array - ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874114/loading-jpg-of-different-sizes-into-numpy-array-valueerror-found-input-variab?rq=1)

ref3: [Number of features of the model must match the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722931/number-of-features-of-the-model-must-match-the-input?rq=1)

ref4: [Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173576/found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples)